# Can we use AspectJ API to weave a .class file by a .aj file at runtime?

Tags: java, logging, aop, aspectj

Basically, I want to create a .java file which can take as input the path to the .class file and name of methods to be logged. Using the aspectJ, we should save the weaved .class file having logs. Is it doable using AspectJ without using ajc on terminal?

I tried to a way and the best I got was to use *org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main*. But it requires aspect path as argument which needs to be fixed. I wanted to find a way to change the contents of the .aj file dynamically during runtime of my program and then use it to weave into the provided .class file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. In this case, the question also suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). You are describing how you want to solve a problem technically, instead of describing which problem you want to solve, unnecessarily narrowing the scope of possible answers. What you seem to want to do, sounds wrong, but with this unclear description I have no way to be sure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.